# how to use JQuery to parse this json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON:

```
{
  "jsonDept": [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "DeptName": "aaaa "
    }, {
      "Id": "2",
      "DeptName": "bbb "
    }, {
      "Id": "6",
      "DeptName": "ccc "
    }, {
      "Id": "7",
      "DeptName": "ddd "
    }, {
      "Id": "8",
      "DeptName": "eee "
    }, {
      "Id": "9",
      "DeptName": "fff "
    }, {
      "Id": "12",
      "DeptName": "haha "
    }, {
      "Id": "13",
      "DeptName": "test1 "
    }, {
      "Id": "14",
      "DeptName": "test2 "
    }, {
      "Id": "10",
      "DeptName": "tmd "
    }, {
      "Id": "11",
      "DeptName": "tnnd "
    }
  ]
}
```

And my JQuery:

```
function loadDepartmentList() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "QueryDepartment.ashx",
        //data: "",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            // how to read json here? this is not working
            $.each(data, function () {
                alert("Name: " + this.DeptName);
            });
        }
    })
}
```

but alert shows "undefined", and only popup once.

What I want to do is parse this json, and generate html `<ul><li>DeptName</li></ul>` and put the html into a div.

I googled many codes, they are not working. I think it may be the problem with the begining string "jsonDept".

Can anyone write a working script for this json? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The returned object contains one property, that is `jsonDept`. It is the `jsonDept` property which contains the array of department information.

```
function loadDepartmentList() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "QueryDepartment.ashx",
        //data: "",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            // how to read json here? this is not working
            $.each(data.jsonDept, function () {
                alert("Name: " + this.DeptName);
            });
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Maybe add an explanation for the OP for why you use `data.jsonDept`, even if some of us understand it

Answer (score 0):

Is this you want to parse json array in to the  HTML list "ul li DeptName /li /ul" ?

Create id for UL

```
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

function:

```
     function loadDepartmentList() {
       $.ajax({
          url: "QueryDepartment.ashx",
           //data: "",
           type: "GET",
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function (data) {            
           $.each(data.jsonDept, function () {
              $('#lsit').append('<li>'+this.DeptName+'</li>');
           });
        }
    })
  }
```

Hope this will give some ideas..